# VideoView cat play this video file while loading over HTTP

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I am using VideoView to fetch and play video over HTTP. But while it loads it on ***Emulator*** , it always says.  **cat play this video file**

**Couldn't open http://somesite.com/20067279_VIDEO_HIGH_H264.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:**

It also looks like it trying to fetch data from ContentResolver rather than HTTP.

Also if i paste the video file url in android chrome browser it does play as usual, so i dont think it is anything related to Codec problems. the files are mostly mp4 and 3gp.

I cant figure out whats going wrong.

**Below is the code for video view**

```
final VideoView fileVideoView=(VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.file_video);
fileVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileContent.url));
        fileVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                fileVideoView.start();
            }
        });
```

**NOTE**
I also have set permission for INTERNET in mainfest.